# Precomputed distance matrix in DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan, rapids

Reading around, I find it is possible to pass a precomputed distance matrix into [SKLearn DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html). Unfortunately, I don't know how to pass it for calculation.

Say I have a 1D array with 100 elements, with just the names of the nodes. Then I have a 2D matrix, 100x100 with the distance between each element (in the same order).

I know I have to call it:

`db = DBSCAN(eps=2, min_samples=5, metric="precomputed")`

For a distance between nodes of 2 and a minimum of 5 node clusters. Also, use "precomputed" to indicate to use the 2D matrix. But how do I pass the info for the calculation?

The same question could apply if using RAPIDS [CUML DBScan](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#dbscan) function (GPU accelerated).

Answer (score 10):

[documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html):

> ```
> class sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(eps=0.5, *, min_samples=5, metric='euclidean', 
> metric_params=None, algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=None, n_jobs=None)
> [...]
> ```

> ```
> [...]
> metricstring, or callable, default=’euclidean’
> The metric to use when calculating distance between instances in a feature array. If 
> metric is a string or callable, it must be one of the options allowed by 
> sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances for its metric parameter. If metric is 
> “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix and must be square. X may be a 
> Glossary, in which case only “nonzero” elements may be considered neighbors for  
> DBSCAN.
> [...]
> ```

So, the way you normally call this is:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

clustering = DBSCAN()
DBSCAN.fit(X)
```

if you have a distance matrix, you do:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

clustering = DBSCAN(metric='precomputed')
clustering.fit(distance_matrix)
```

Comment: So X will be the square matrix with the distances pairwise, right?

Shouldn't be metric='precomputed' instead of metric='fixed' ?

Comment: could you please review the details I give bellow? Thx

Comment: True, X should be pairwise distance matrix, and the metric should be 'precomputed'. Answer from @warped is true.